# open xml file error to log

Tags: python, logging, exception

when I run my python script in command line I get an error output when trying to retrieve an xml file. I would like to write this error message to a logfile.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('fileChecker')
hdlr = logging.FileHandler('./fileChecker.log')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hdlr)
logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

try:
    fileXML = mylibrary.getXML(enf, name)
    logger.info('got xml file ok')
except TypeError:
    errorCount += 1
    logger.error('we have a problem')
```

mylibrary.getXML() is throwing an error here that I can see in commandline output.
how do I get that to be written to my log file?

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the exception object that was raised:

```
try:
    fileXML = myLibrary.getXML(enf, name)
    logger.info('got xml file ok')
except TypeError, e:
    errorCount += 1
    logger.error('We have a problem: ' + str(e))
```

Note that if you're using the Python `logging` module, there is also the [Logger.exception](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception) method.

Comment: Thanks, but if I do that I just get NoneTYpe excpetion. Saying object is not subscriptable.

Comment: I would like to log the error message that myLibrary.getXML(enf, name) outputs to the terminal.

Comment: You'll have to provide some more information, for example the actual output you want to achieve.

Comment: for example, depending on what xml file I am trying to retrieve I may get a message like 'permission denied', at least in command line I do.
The other error is file doesn't exist. when I write to log I'd like to have more info than just 'NoneType'. Permission denied would be good.But how do I get it to write that to log instead of command line? I guess that command line message is output by getXML()

Comment: With the code above you just catch exceptions of the type `TypeError`. If you want to catch other exceptions you have to update the `except` clause appropriately. See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html). You can use the [traceback module](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) to print stacktraces if that's what you want.